# Product of random variables is uniform

Tags: uniform-distribution, random

Require a random variable $X$, $0 < X < 1$ with a distribution such that the product of two independent samples from the distribution is uniformly distributed on the interval (0,1).

Answer (score 1):

If $U \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$ then observe that $-\ln(U) \sim \text{Exp}(1)$. Hence if $X, X'$ are i.i.d. such that $XX' \overset{d}{=} U$, then $-\ln(X)-\ln(X') \overset{d}{=} \text{Exp}(1)$.

But also, $\text{Exp}(1) = \text{Gamma}(1,1)$, and we know that the sum of independent Gamma distributions with the same rate parameter is a Gamma distribution with the sum of the shape parameters, so we deduce that we must have $-\ln(X) \sim \text{Gamma}(1/2,1)$.

Comment: That look quite straightforward but I'm now having trouble with numerical tests.  To get a uniform sampled product distribution from 1,000 independent pairs of numbers with the Gamma PDF,  I'm having to use Gamma( 1/1.6, 1) rather than 1/2  in your formula which seems implausible somehow !

Comment: @eulogy $\text{Gamma}(1/2,1)$ seems to be the correct distribution for me when I tried numerical experiments. Perhaps 1,000 samples of pairs is not sufficient for the distribution to arise empirically. Remember also that $X$ is $\exp(-\text{Gamma(1/2,1)})$, and that the shape parameter is $1/2$ and the rate is $1$.